# Toggling class in calendar component by element Id highlights same date in every month

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've written a simple calendar in Vue. The days of the month are displayed by using a v-for which creates an array of $refs. Each date element is also given an unique ID. I want to highlight a day by clicking on it, which works. However, the same day in every month is also highlighted. Example, if I click on May 25th, the 25th of every other month is also highlighted, even though I'm the toggling the class based on the id of that element.

How can I highlight only the selected day?

Here is the code for the highlight method.

```
highlightDay(index) {
                let selected = this.$refs.day[index].id;
                if (!this.$refs.day[index].classList.contains("today")) {
                    this.$refs.day.forEach(el => {
                        if (el.classList.contains("selected-day")) {
                            el.classList.toggle("selected-day");
                        }
                    });
                    document
                        .getElementById(selected)
                        .classList.toggle("selected-day");
                }
            }
```

Here is a link to the project.
https://codepen.io/reticent67/pen/EzWomG

Comment: You're applying a class to n-th day, without saving the month. Instead, store the day ***and*** the month in your `vm` and apply `selected-day` class based on a method comparing both the day and the month with what's set as selected in `vm` (i.e: `class="{'selected-day': isSelected(day)}"`)

Comment: I would also add that you should try to avoid accessing the dom directly with $refs and getElementById.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for your guidance. I understand what you are saying I need to do, I'm just not sure how to go about it. I can get the day and month of the selected item, but I'm not quite sure what I'm comparing them to. Can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing comes from using DOM elements, through `$refs`, to store your 
selected day.

I would encourage you to move away from that type of logic (which I call jQuery logic and typically leads to complex DOM manipulations, even in simple cases, like yours) into one that's specific to SPA's, where you use the virtual model (typically referred to as `vm`) as source of truth **<sup>1</sup>**.

Getting back to your component, instead of storing your selected day as `id` of the currently rendered day, I would store it as an array, having 3 elements: `[day, month, year]` **<sup>2</sup>**.

To pass this to the rendered layer, you should use a method:

```
isSelected(index) {
  return this.selectedDay === [index, this.month, this.year];
}
```

with the day markup containing something like this:

```
<div 
  v-for="(date, date_index) in months[month].days" 
  :key="date_index" 
  :class="[{ 'selected-day': isSelected(date_index) }]">{{ date }}
</div>
```

I've implemented this into your example [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/VOxwgO).
Note I also simplfied the `highlightDay()` method. I simply set `selectedDay` as the aforementioned array or unset it if they're equal (to enable deselect with click on selected one).

---

**<sub>[1] -</sub>**  <sub>Do note that in more complex cases, where the source of truth needs to be shared between app components, Vue provides a specialized module for managing data, called Vuex (but we don't use that here).</sub>

**<sub>[2] -</sub>**  <sub>To clean the data of observers (used by Vue to listen to mutations), I stored the array in `selectedDay` as a JSON string.</sub>

Comment: Wow, so much simpler and cleaner.  I re-read the Vue docs and an article about accessing the DOM directly through `$refs` but it didn't really click until I saw your solution in action.  Thank you, friend.